# Reading text from website doesnt work (BufferedReader, InputStream) Android, Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, url, web, bufferedreader

Im trying to read text from a website. Im using a tutorial.
Here is the code of my java

```
package nl.liacs.team6.stapp;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Jokes extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    try 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.jokes);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        //dit is t textview element, gevonden door id van de XML layout jokes
        TextView myListView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.netResult);

        //proberen met internet te connecten
        try{
            //maak nieuw client object
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            //post to onze url, site is voorbeeld
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://ephemeraltech.com/demo/android_tutorial20.php");

            //voor post uit en get response
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            //get message from response
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            //get content van message
            InputStream webs = entity.getContent();

            //nu hebben we response, convert to string

            try
            {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(webs, "iso-8859-1"), 8);

                //lees 1 lijn van text
                myListView.setText(reader.readLine());
                //sluiten
                webs.close();

            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }

}
catch(Exception e){
}

}// onCreate
}// Jokes
```

HEre is the xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:id="@+id/netResult"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and yes i added permission to the android manifest

nothing shows up when i run it

can anyone help me? i dont know what im doing wrong

Here is the log

```
 05-06 10:39:15.501: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(887): setKernelCountSet(10012, 0)   failed with errno -2
 05-06 10:39:16.371: I/ActivityManager(887): START {cmp=nl.liacs.team6.stapp/.Info} from pid 1488
 05-06 10:39:16.371: W/WindowManager(887): Failure taking screenshot for (180x300) to layer 21010
 05-06 10:39:16.660: I/ActivityManager(887): Displayed nl.liacs.team6.stapp/.Info: +267ms
```

Thank you so much!!

**EDIT**

```
 public class Jokes extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.jokes);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        //dit is t textview element, gevonden door id van de XML layout jokes
        TextView myListView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.netResult);
        new loadSomeStuff().execute(FILENAME);      
        }// onCreate

public class loadSomeStuff extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //proberen met internet te connecten
        try{
            //maak nieuw client object
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            //post to onze url, site is voorbeeld
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://ephemeraltech.com/demo/android_tutorial20.php");

            //voor post uit en get response
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            //get message from response
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            //get content van message
            InputStream webs = entity.getContent();

            //nu hebben we response, convert to string

            try
            {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(webs, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                //dit is t textview element, gevonden door id van de XML layout jokes
                TextView myListView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.netResult);
                //lees 1 lijn van text
                myListView.setText(reader.readLine());
                //sluiten
                webs.close();

            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }
 return null;
}
 }
 }
```

i dont know what im doing and what everthing means, its all new to me but thanks for all of you guys help.

Comment: have you checked weather response is coming or not?? and how you are directly setting the text to List View? without parsing ? or even without knowing what is type of data and size of it???

Comment: have you tried to debug it ? please try to get what response is coming from server....

Answer (score 0):

First of all please add following code in to manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Then put all your networking code either in to thread or in to doinbackground method of async task.

This will solve your problem.

You can call to current async task using

```
new loadstuff.execute("url");

public class loadSomeStuff extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

   String result=null;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //proberen met internet te connecten
        try{
            //maak nieuw client object
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            //post to onze url, site is voorbeeld
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://ephemeraltech.com/demo/android_tutorial20.php");

            //voor post uit en get response
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            //get message from response
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            //get content van message
            InputStream webs = entity.getContent();

            //nu hebben we response, convert to string

            try
            {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(webs, "iso-8859-1"), 8);

                //text view removed from here
               result=reader.readline();

                //sluiten
                webs.close();

            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }
 return null;
}

 onPostExecute(){

          //declare your text view here & assign result to your text view.
          myTextView.setText(result);

   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I dont what Im doing
I have edited my code in the original question
First, i have this new class loadSomeStuff that execute something but FILENAME cannot be resolved to a variable, what do i put there?
and second, i want to read text from a website, what arguments do i ut for the asynctask?
(String, Integer, String) is correct?
Third, now I understand that asynctask returns something, how do I return the text?

thanks again.